# R: rbind a row replacing existing rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have the following df, with redundant column3 values "bbb" and "ddd"

```
  col1 col2 col3
    u1    1  aaa
    u1    1  bbb
    u1    1  bbb
    u1    1  bbb
    u1    1  ccc
    u1   -1  ddd
    u1   -1  ddd
```

I wish to create the following df, where col3-redundant rows are replace by a single row with **col2 = SUM** of replaced rows:

```
col1 col2 col3
    u1    1  aaa
    u1    3  bbb
    u1    1  ccc
    u1   -2  ddd
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
      group_by(col1, col3) %>% 
      summarise(col2=sum(col2))

 #   col1 col3 col2
 #1   u1  aaa    1
 #2   u1  bbb    3
 #3   u1  ccc    1
 #4   u1  ddd   -2
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(col2=sum(col2)), by=list(col1, col3)]
```

Or using `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT col1, col3, 
        sum(col2) as col2 
        from df
        group by col1, col3')
 #   col1 col3 col2
 #1   u1  aaa    1
 #2   u1  bbb    3
 #3   u1  ccc    1
 #4   u1  ddd   -2
```

Or using `base R`

```
aggregate(.~col1+col3, df, sum)
#   col1 col3 col2
#1   u1  aaa    1
#2   u1  bbb    3
#3   u1  ccc    1
#4   u1  ddd   -2
```